# Return coordinates of pixels

Tags: assembly, mips

I have to implement a function that converts a row number and column number of a pixel on the screen to the memory address for the corresponding pixel. Keep in mind the dimensions of the screen (32 pixels wide, 16 pixels high). The pixel at row 0 and column 0 is at the top left of the address in register $gp. Each pixel is 32 bits.

I have no idea on how to return the address of the said pixel. Here is the code that I wrote:

```
.globl main

.data

amountOfRows:    .word 16  # The mount of rows of pixels
amountOfColumns: .word 32  # The mount of columns of pixels

promptRows: .asciiz "Please enter the row number:\n"
promptCols: .asciiz "Please enter the column number:\n"

msgShowMemoryAddress: .asciiz "The memory address for the pixel is:\n"

.text

main:

    li $v0, 4       # print string
    la $a0, promptRows  # message to ask the user for the row number
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 5  # read integer
    syscall    # ask the user for a row number
    
    # add code here ...
    move $t0, $v0 # $t0 is y
    
    
    li $v0 , 4 #print string
    la $a0, promptCols #message to ask the user for the column number
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 5 #read int
    syscall #ask the user for a column number
    
    move $t1, $v0 #$t1 is x
    j index
index:
    sll $t3, $t0, 5 # multiply $t0 by 32 and set it to $t3
    add $t4,$t3,$t1 # $t4 = $t3 + x
    j offset
    
offset:
    sll $t5,$t4,2 # multiply $t4 by 4 and set it to $t5
    j final
final:
    add $gp,$t5,$gp #set gp to $t5 + $gp to get the address of the given pixel coordinates
    
    # return the adress of gp??? (wrong idk how)
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0,msgShowMemoryAddress
    syscall
    la $a0, $gp
    syscall
    
    j exit


exit:

    li $v0, 10  # syscall to end the program
    syscall
```

Comment: The way I read your assignment, you should create a **function**. So put your stuff into a function, where you leave the result in `$v0` (by convention). In `main` invoke your function and then do whatever you want with the result (print it I suppose).

Comment: Don't modify `$gp`, that must not be changed.  You're not trying to modify `$gp` to refer to the pixel, if you do that, and ever want to compute a 2nd pixel, you'll have lost the base address.

Comment: In order to return a value you have to have a function, and when you have the function then, you have to call it.